# Cupy unable to find CUDA repository

Tags: python, cupy

I am trying to use cupy and I have installed CUDA 10.2 and the corresponding version of cupy but I get this error when I try and run my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lasse/PycharmProjects/AI/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cupy as cp
  File "C:\Users\lasse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\cupy\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    _environment._setup_win32_dll_directory()  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\lasse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\cupy\_environment.py", line 37, in _setup_win32_dll_directory
    raise RuntimeError('CUDA path could not be detected.')
RuntimeError: CUDA path could not be detected.
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code leading to this error ?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that `CUDA_PATH` environment variable is correctly set (e.g., `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2`). Generally it should be set automatically by the CUDA installer.

CuPy discovers CUDA path in the following order.

1. `CUDA_PATH` environment variable.
2. The parent directory of `nvcc` command. CuPy looks for `nvcc` command in each directory set in `PATH` environment variable.
3. `/usr/local/cuda` (not applicable for Windows)

https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/install.html#working-with-custom-cuda-installation